# How can I jump back to the active editor tab?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

Is there a hotkey to jump back to the active editor tab from a tool window?

I have a hotkey for the docker tool window (alt+d), but when I switch to that tool window I'm usually in the attached console and once im in there i cant use alt+d to close/minimize it to switch back. I can do alt+tab but that just brings up the switcher and I have to choose which file I want.

Is there a hotkey (or mapping I could set a hotkey for) to switch directly to the editor tab that is currently open?

Answer (score 1):

You can try SHIFT+ESCAPE to minimize the current tool window and return to the editor or simply ESCAPE to close the tool window and jump back to the active editor